# Approach for Change tracking mechanism with concurrent writes

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, concurrency, rdbms

I need to implement data synchronization in a distributed system taking into account concurrent writes to the data table.
The export from Main DB should read only changed rows.

Common advice is to use triggers, marking rows with timestamp of data update or consequent revision; and tell this timestamp/revision_number to the remote system.
E.g. [What is the best approach to pull "Delta" data into Analytics DB from a highly transactional DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34849214/what-is-the-best-approach-to-pull-delta-data-into-analytics-db-from-a-highly-t)

But the problem with concurrent writes is in the moment of time when commit takes place. Here is a problem:

```
[time 00:00] Transaction A starts writing a big batch of data;
             marking rows with timestamp [00:00].
[time 00:02]     Transaction B starts writing a small amount of data;
                 going to mark rows with timestamp [00:02].
[time 00:03]     Transaction B finishes writing and commit happens.
[time 00:10]         Export is done to the remote part of the system. 
                     Isolation level is ReadCommitted, so it gets know only data from transaction B, timestamp 00:02.
[time 00:15] Transaction A finishes writing and commit happens.
             Remote system never receves this data(!)
```

I like the solution [Change tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server) in MSSQL, but I keep in mind our intention to migrate to PostgreSQL soon. So I have to implement a general solution.

What is the correct approach to solve this problem?